# Is there a way to add path to sys.path automatically when activating an python environment?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm trying to add project_root to sys.path when activating the project environment

(currently conda, but it can be pyenv, poetry..)

The project_root might be different for people depending on where they created the project_root in their local file system.

So is there a way for me to setup so that when other people download (git clone) and setup the project, and when they activate the environment, they will have the project-root added to their `sys.path` ?

I was thinking , to use hook script for conda (or similar), but i'm not sure how I 'll let it know the project-root (which can be different for different people)

- edit

Why do I want this?

Suppose you have a new script which wants to use some of the other files in the project, you need to import the other file.

Then you need to tell the path , if project root is in sys.path, any script can import file relative from the project root, not from its current location

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @TedElliott edited the op

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`PYTHONPATH` environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH).

The paths set in `PYTHONPATH` will be automatically pre-pended to the `sys.path` list after the path in which the main script resides.